# Website Blocks Dropping in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Hello i have recently changed a theme i have from fluid width to fixed width. I thought it went well till i noticed it on internet explorer and i saw that it hadnt. Its ok when you view it with the broswer window not on full but as you can see from the link on full screen everything is all over the place
[my website](http://onlinebanter.com/latest)

Ive been trying to sort it but with a lack of firebug etc on ie im struggling a bit.

Does anyone with a good knowledge of these things know a fix for me?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the width from #center. Okay you should put max-width of 500px on #center.

Comment: actually its as i feared STP. Now on Chrome the #center is full width and its the full width of the screen with both sidebars dropped.

Comment: you can see it when viewing a piece of 'post' content

Comment: Looking at it on post pages now. Let me inspect, I think the problem may stem from a html issue as well.

Comment: thanks STP much appreciated. Its on the frontpage as well. ive been messing about with stuff to fix it. i dont understand why video posts seem ok.

Comment: Updated to reflect the fix for the post page as well.

Comment: thats done the job STP. Much appreciated. I was nearly just gonna bin this theme and go get a fixed width one and add an extrasidebar myself. That would require me taking a sickie from work tomorrow so your help is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: No Problem, could you give me a point arrow up for the right answer.