# Strange Blank Space on Left of Main Content in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer

Hello i dont know if this is related to a [previous question that i asked on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13556353/website-blocks-dropping-in-ie)

but it would seem so. I thought it bets to ask a new question as that last question was resolved.

You can [view my website here](http://onlinebanter.com/latest)

As you can see the center coloum is pushed over to the right on Internet Explorer. It seems ok on other browsers. I was hoping it was just the table width but its not as you can see if you view any other content. Ive been looking into it but ive not had much luck.

Can anyone see why this is so in Internet Explorer? If i can sort this then i think that after 7 years my website might actually be considered 'done' and i can get my life back so all help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the relevant (original) code here in the question?  That way this will be useful to future visitors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the Internet Explorer Box model.  The padding is inside the content rather than outside.  see - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug.

Remove the `padding-left` in you IE specific style sheet.

Comment: Thanks Kami. Truth be told i dont think i have an IE style sheet. I will go learn how to add one and i will brb. thanks

Comment: heh heh that worked and i learnt something new. thanks very much for your help Kami :)

Comment: I think that this is related to this. I am getting an error for 'blank.gif not found' across my pages. oops didnt mean to post that. the error is found at onlinebanter.com ... gs-riches/all-ie-only.css the IE css file i made. I have no css int here barr the padding-left.

Comment: I cannot see that url, or find an all-ie-only.css file on the link to the site above.  Not sure what the issue is, probably file path is not valid.